# 26 X 1.75 front and 26 X 2.0 rear tyre?

Tags: tire, 26-inch

can I use 26 X 1.75 for front and 26 X 2.0 for rear? the tube size is the same.

Bike : Rockrider 5.0
Terrain : mostly Road, occasionally off-road.

Comment: This is not a complete question. Please provide a lot more detail: what bike? what rims? on what terrain do you ride? why do you want different tires?

Comment: Its Rockrider 5.0 , I ride mostly on road, occasional off road. I am not able to get tires of size 26 X 2.0 in my country. Its not available anywhere.

Comment: As long as it fits the rim and fits in the frame I don't think there will be problems

Comment: The larger tyre in the rear could allow you to ride through terrain with a lower pressure meaning more traction. There might be a benefit.

Comment: You can have a look [here](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#iso) (at the green and red table) if your front rim is compatible with such a tire. It almost certainly is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeap- no reason not to. I do the same on my mountain bike, I prefer the width of the wider rear to enable stability/grip whilst the front is just wide enough to steer in the direction. Most inner tubes will work over quite a range of tyre sizes & the same for rims. Make sure you check the specification of both if you are concerned.

Comment: agreed, seems like a good choice to me

Comment: FWIW, I much prefer bigger on the front and narrower in back, but where I ride is generally hard pack and there isn't much advantage to having a wider rear tire.